# Quasar SSR app, "window is not defined" from vue-router

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, quasar

I'm taking a fairly simple Vue app built with Quasar, and adding ssr.

I'm using the Quasar CLI, and added ssr with `quasar mode add ssr`.  This created the `src-ssr/` folder and files as expected.

When I launch it with `quasar dev -m ssr`, I get:

```
 App • Opening default browser at http://localhost:9100/

/Users/stevex/src/myapp/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.cjs:478
    const { history, location } = window;
                                  ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at useHistoryStateNavigation (/Users/stevex/src/myapp/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.cjs:478:35)
    at createWebHistory (/Users/stevex/src/myapp/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.cjs:570:31)
    at Module.eval [as default] (/src/router/index.ts:14:14)
    at __vite_ssr_exports__.default (/.quasar/app.js:91:44)
    at async eval (/Users/stevex/src/myapp/.quasar/server-entry.js:86:9)

Node.js v18.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, it was the history mode.

I was using `createWebHistory` in `routes/index.ts`, but for SSR the history mode must be `createMemoryHistory`.  With that change, the server-side-rendered page loads.

Details here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#memory-mode

The default createHistory checks for the environment and picks a compatible one; I'd replaced that.  Here's the default, which works:

```
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history'
    ? createWebHistory
    : createWebHashHistory;
```